# Unable to scroll Up completely in a scrollView when Software Keyboard is up

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I am developing a full screen Android application, and here is the weird problem I am facing:
I am unable to scroll the scrollView completely when the software keyboard is up.No problem if the activity is **not a full screen activity** (I checked).Attached is the xml code snippet and iamges:

Normally viewing the activity:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_RJcrMK6rlORXRDc1UxMFRYSFE/edit?usp=sharing

When the keyboard is UP:

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_RJcrMK6rlOenhZeHFCTEhFZ1U/edit?usp=sharing

I am filling the Table Layout dynamically from Database rows

Here is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Spent For :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >
        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TableLayout1"
            android:text="Given By :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/TableLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" >
        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TableLayout2"
            android:text="Enter a description :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```